# Logistic Regression Prediction Threshold Error

Tags: python

I am using logistic regression to predict a binary variable setting threshold to .60. Accuracy of the model its giving me an error

I am using `predict_proba()` to set the threshold to .60, but when I am trying to find the accuracy of the model, it's giving me the error:

> '<' not supported between instances of 'bool' and 'str'

```
X=df[["age",  "breed"]]
y=df["animal"]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train1,X_test1,y_train1,y_test1=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.30,random_state=0)

# import the class
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression


model = LogisticRegression(class_weight="balanced")
model.fit(X_train1, y_train1)


preds = (model4.predict_proba(X_test1)[:,1] >= 0.60)
print(preds)
#from sklearn import metrics
#print(" Prediction Accuracy:",metrics.accuracy_score(y_test1, prediction4))
#from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
dat= accuracy_score(y_test1, preds)
print(dat)
```

Output of pred is
[False False False ...  True  True False]

Comment: How many classes does `df["animal"]` contain and can you show a snippet of this in your question? Your problem is that the dtype of this series is a string

Comment: 2  classes --->  dog and cat

Comment: Yep that is your problem. I have added an answer that I will edit to reflect the use of dog and cat

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `y_train1` does not contain a boolean array either. Check what is in the `df["animal"]` Series and decide which class is positive (e.g., if it is filled with `'dog'` and `'cat'` then then the follow snippet would work, assuming that "cat" is True):

```
dat= accuracy_score(y_test1=="cat", preds)
```

---

You can use the `classes_` attribute on the logistic regression model (`model.classes_`) to see if `'cat'` or `'dog'` is assigned to 0 or 1

Comment: Dog is False and Cat is True

Comment: Updated to reflect that

Comment: I am getting the accuracy but its very low showing 0.90. but when i do normal logistic regression with out threshold its giving me .98. I think there is some thing i am  doing wrong here

Comment: Are you sure that you have the classes the right way around (i.e., is cal definitely true?) What is the output of `print(model.classes_)`

Comment: the output is ['dog' 'cat']

Comment: How is the accuracy when you predict on the `X_train1`, `y_train1` set using this same code above?

Comment: accuracy  turns out to be 0.90. i am trying to create a confusion matrixfrom sklearn import metrics
cnf_matrix = metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test1=="cat",preds)
cnf_matrix

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221610/discussion-between-zac-and-nick).